Dynamically Load Formie Entry Field Options
I have a Formie multi-page form that has an Entry field set to display as radio buttons.  This entry radio field is populated with "Clinic" entries, which are channel type entries.  Each clinic entry has a name and address field.
What I want to do is have an address field above this radio field so a user can enter in a physical address/location and then I use that entered address to dynamically set the clinic radio options. The point of this is to only show nearby clinics or clinics within that state.
Is the only way to accomplish this through a Formie Custom Field or am I overlooking an obvious solution?
Thanks!
